# Web Farm Framework on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, web-farm, iis

I'm having trouble installing the Web Farm Framework (2.0) in Windows Server 2012.  Has it been integrated in with IIS8 or another feature like AAR? I've looked in the Web Platform Installer and it is not listed.  Web Farm Framework 1.1 is listed but seems to not work when installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2012 is not a supported operating system for the Web Farm Framework yet, as per this article: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27723. Also, WFF 2.x requires Web Deploy 2.0 and Web Platform Installer 3.0, neither of which are supported on Windows Server 2012 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25230 and http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6164).

Answer (score 0):

While the Web Farm Framework itself is not supported on Windows Server 2012, they have included some articles on how to setup similar functionality.

Here is an article from Microsoft that describes the steps for setting it up on Windows Server 2012.
Overview: Build a Web Farm with IIS Servers:
http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/scenario-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers/overview-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers